# joining wide tables (10s of unique cols)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiples tables which need to be joined on multiple common attributes such the different attributes can be shown in a single table.

table1

```
+--------+---------+-------+
|  make  |  model  | r_yr  |
+--------+---------+-------+
| toyota | corolla |  1999 |
| toyota |  camry  |  2002 |
| toyota |  qualis |  2004 |
| toyota |  rav4   |  2006 |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

table2

```
+--------+---------+--------+
|  make  |  model  |  kms   |
+--------+---------+--------+
| toyota | corolla |  25000 |
| toyota |  camry  |  50000 |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

table4

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|  make  |  model  | mileage |
+--------+---------+---------+
| toyota | corolla |      20 |
| toyota |  qualis |      25 |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

table5

```
+--------+----------+-------+
|  make  |  model   | colr  |
+--------+----------+-------+
| toyota |  camry   | blue  |
| toyota |  rav4    | green |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

I'm doing the following to join the results

```
select a.make, a.model,a.r_yr,b.kms,c.mileage,d.colr
    from table1 as a
    left join table2 as b
    on b.make=a.make and b.model=a.model and b.r_yr=a.r_yr
    left join table3 as c
    on c.make=a.make and c.model=a.model and c.r_yr=a.r_yr
    left join table4 as d
    on d.make=a.make and d.model=a.model and d.r_yr=a.r_yr
```

This gives a table like below

```
+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
|  make  |  model  | r_yr  |  kms  |  mileage |  colr  |
+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
| toyota | corolla |  1999 | 25000 |       20 |        |
| toyota |  camry  |  2002 | 50000 |          |  blue  |
| toyota |  qualis |  2004 |       |       25 |        |
| toyota |  rav4   |  2006 |       |          | green  |
+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
```

However the issue I have is that, for the real data set I'm working with, there are 5 `common cols` per table and around 20-40 `unique attributes` per table requiring to specify 20-40 col names in the query in the form of `b.kms, ....,c.mileage, ......,d.colr,....`. Is there a work around to not having to specify those unique columns by specifying all except the `common cols` or other ways ?

Comment: The main problem here is that your complete table design is horrible. Can you change it?

Comment: @juergend - changing the table design is not an option - outside my control.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you're stuck with a terrible table design, then terrible queries are generally an unavoidable result.

Comment: @MattGibson what is terrible about having 10s of columns in a table ?

Comment: @user3206440 I suggest looking up why someone would want to normalize  (or denormalize) a database. If you had an abstract integer like `car_id` as a primary key, it would take up less space in the database and queries would execute faster. (Also, most RDBMS's can compare integers faster than characters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do something like `SELECT all except x,y,z ...`

But you can simplify this query using `USING` clause instead of `JOIN ... ON`

---

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fa97a/6

```
select *
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b
USING (make, model)
left join table3 as c
USING (make, model)
left join table4 as d
USING (make, model)
```

---

```
|   make |   model | r_yr |    kms | mileage |   colr |
|--------|---------|------|--------|---------|--------|
| toyota |   camry | 2002 |  50000 |  (null) |   blue |
| toyota | corolla | 1999 |  25000 |      20 | (null) |
| toyota |  qualis | 2004 | (null) |      25 | (null) |
| toyota |    rav4 | 2006 | (null) |  (null) |  green |
```

Note: In the above example I am using only two common columns `(make, model)` since in your example `r_yr` is not a common column because it is only in table1